# How can I lock the scale when panning?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I'm just wondering if there's any way to easily lock the map scale when panning etc. For example, suppose I set the scale to 1:100,000 - panning with the mouse will then alter that slightly, which can be a real nuisance sometimes.

Comment: Are you aware that on any map of the earth's surface, the scale varies from point to point and even depends on *direction*? What, then, would it mean to "lock" something that is so ill-defined? I don't know exactly what QGIS reports, but typically a GIS will tell you the scale in the horizontal direction at the center of the map.  When you pan the map, it's inevitable that this scale will change: that is forced on us by the mathematics of curved surfaces and flat projections.

Comment: I think this is something that ArcMap "can" do that QGIS "doesn't"...

Answer (score 3):

**The simple answer is 'not in current version.'** There is a feature request for this noted in [ticket #2281](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/2218), and a similar request in [ticket #5833](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5833), which goes a bit further in that it affords zooming at the frozen scale. As noted above by @whuber, depending upon your current projection (or lack thereof) and scale, the scale is apt to change during panning.

**The complex answer is 'you can create a plugin to do this.'** While probably not the answer you are looking for, you can craft a PyQGIS or C++ plugin that adds a small dock (or other) widget to the interface. Inside that, you can add a check box for setting the scale freeze and maybe a spin box for defining a particular scale.

In the underlying code, you can connect to the [QgsMapCanvas::mapCanvasRefreshed() signal](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#acc653c8ef1e58ac16c41fffcabe11ee3) or [QgsMapCanvas::scaleChanged(double) signal](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#aa82160009cbce773dcb62b3d181e121f) and verify the [QgsMapCanvas::scale](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#aa47a3e45a5d2d166d360ee28eb2edc03) has not changed; and, if it has, use [QgsMapCanvas::zoomScale(double)](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a0ff77ba14d5443e13071f6766bbf25eb) to reset it.

This approach is not ideal since the correction occurs *after* the canvas refresh, and requires an *additional* refresh to fix it (though I have not verified this with the scaleChanged signal). But, it is a workaround that can work with current and older QGIS versions. Adding the feature to the core of QGIS would no doubt allow for correction prior to map canvas rendering, thereby skipping the secondary refresh issue.

Please add your voice to either of those tickets, and maybe look into [help funding the project or a developer to add the feature or plugin for you](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/donations.html) (if the coding is a bit more than you care to do).