# How to deactivate zoom on the mouse wheel?

Tags: qgis, scale

I need to fixed scale in canvas in QGIS but I didn't find this function. If I fix scale it is impossible to make zoom in or zoom out into canvas. Only one move which layers loaded can be do are top/down and left and right.

Comment: Fixed scale ~= fixed zoom level. Which behavior do you expect?

Comment: I would like that my canvas don't move when I rotate scroll of mouse. Canvas scale defined in 1:50.000 doesn't change to other scale.

Comment: You also mentioned zooming in your question. What do you expect there?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my english isn't good. But, in my question I was trying explain what I would like to do. Is my question clear? In Arcgis is very simple what I would like to do. There, there is data frame properties that I can go to data frame tab and than I select "fixed scale" which I wish. After that, it impossible to do zoom in data frame. It is the same that I try to do in Qgis, but I didn't find this option there. Thanks for your atention.

Comment: I believe the entire question body is stating/describing desired behavior - not a conflict or something happening that shouldn't be. The term for "top/down and left and right" is panning (to pan in a direction). Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73708/ which states that as of 2.0 you can't. May have changed in versions since then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the **Mouse wheel action** in Options | Map Tools to **Nothing**.
This deactivates zooming with the mouse.